# Loading URL with unique Android or iOS device id in webview

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I know how to get the device unique id in flutter, but when I add it as a parameter to url and call it with webview, I can't get the result I want. When I call the following function, webview is loaded with empty device id parameter because it is working ASYNC and not yet completed and not returning any value.

```
    Future<String> _getId() async {
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
    IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    return iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor; // unique ID on iOS
  } else {
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidDeviceInfo.androidId; // unique ID on Android
  }
}
```

The webview loading function is below;

```
String webViewUrl;
_getId().then((id) {
  webViewUrl = "http://websiteblabla.com/?deviceid="+id;
  return WebviewScaffold(
      url: webViewUrl,
      withJavascript: true,
      withZoom: false
  );
}
```

How can I get URL with unique Android or iOS device id in webview when it is ready?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Future function or method which will return WebviewScaffold widget when everything is ready. And the use it with FutureBuilder. It would look something like this.

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: _buildWebview(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData) return Center(
         child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
      return snapshot.data;
   },
),

Future<Widget> _buildWebview() async {
  await _getId().then((id) {
    webViewUrl = "http://websiteblabla.com/?deviceid="+id;
    return WebviewScaffold(
      url: webViewUrl,
      withJavascript: true,
      withZoom: false
    );
  }
}
```